# How to pass data to controller

Tags: laravel

I intend to pass ip received in User.php to my HomeController. How can I do this?

```
 $ip = Request::ip();
```

Now I'm looking for the way to pass it to the controller. Then I plan to  broadcast it.

Comment: Please explain how the model class `User.php` is having this line `$ip = Request::ip();`.

Comment: You have a point. User.php is not a proper place for this line. I put it directly to Controller.

Comment: @linuxartisan I guess you can provide an answer to my question.

Comment: Please elaborate. As of now, I am not able to understand what you are trying to do. A little bit of code might help.

Answer (score 0):

**Request IP in laravel using controller**

You should use request facades. Following way:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

 public function index(Request $request)
 {
  dd($request->ip());
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the IP received via the URL or is it tied to the User model?

If it's via URL then it'd be as simple as

```
Route::get('example.com/{ip}', 'Controller@someFunction');
```

then in the controller

```
public function someFunction($ip) {
... //$ip can be used in here
}
```

Or, if say there's an authenticated user with 'ip' as part of the model, you could access it in the controller by grabbing the authenticated user instance:

```
public function someFunction() {
$user = Auth::user();
//$user->ip;
}
```